# @Component viewBindings is deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular

I'm experimenting with Angular 2 and Dart. By the end of [this step of the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/displaying-data.html) the class `DisplayComponent` has a `Component` annotation with `viewBindings` set:

```
@Component(selector: 'display', viewBindings: const [FriendsService])// this viewBinding
@View(...)
class DisplayComponent {
...
}
```

Atom with the angular2-dart plugin tells me that `viewBindings` is deprecated. This seems in-line with [the documentation](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-alpha.42/angular2.core/Component/Component.html).

I've tried simply removing the variable from the annotation but I get an Exception saying `No provider for FriendsService`. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: @EricMartinez Is it a simple drop in change? So `@Component(selector: 'display', viewProviders: const [FriendsService])`? It works, but I want to be sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: You can see change in API DEPRECATION section of the 2.0.0-alpha.41 (2015-10-13) release: @Component(viewBindings: ...) -> @Component(viewProviders: ...) The file change log for all releases is here: [https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Would one of you mind answering the question? then Corey can accept it and the question is shown as answered instead of unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of completeness

In Alpha 46 is viewProviders (viewBindings => viewProviders) and providers (bindings => providers) up to date.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md